# Two bluetooth connection services actions handler

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have two services in which I have implemented code for bluetooth connection with my application.
The first service connects to the printer and the second one to another device.
For example:
**PrinterConnectionService** and **SecondDeviceConnectionService**.
I use the same UUID on both of them to create the communication channel, everything is working fine and the devices are connected and I am able to send/recieve/print from both devices via my application. Now I am trying to check if the devices are connected or not to my application after services are started and I am doing that in the following way:
`public class MainActivity`

```
onCreate() 
startService1() 
startService2()

    private IntentFilter filterForDevice2() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
        return filter;
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver receiveBroadcastForDevice2() {
        broadcastReceiverForDevice2 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d("TAG", " ACTION: " + intent.getAction());
                String action = intent.getAction();
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                Log.d("TAG", "onReceive : " + device);

                 if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action) && device.getAddress().equals(DEV2_MAC_ADDRESS)) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "CONNECTED: "); //Device connected
                   
                }
                else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action) && device.getAddress().equals(DEV2_MAC_ADDRESS)) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "DISCONNECTED: "); //Device disconnected

                }
            }
        };
        return broadcastReceiverForDevice2;
    }

    private IntentFilter filterForPrinter() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
        return filter;
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver receiveBroadcastForPrinter() {
        broadcastReceiverForPrinter = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d("TAG", " Printer ACTION : " + intent.getAction());
                String action = intent.getAction();
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                Log.d("TAG", "onReceive PRINTER: " + device);


                 if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action) && device.getAddress().equals(PrinterConnectionService.PRINTER_MAC_ADDRESS)) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "PRINTER CONNECTED: "); //Device connected
                }
                else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action) && device.getAddress().equals(PrinterConnectionService.PRINTER_MAC_ADDRESS)) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "PRINTER DISCONNECTED: "); //Device disconnected

                }
            }
        };
        return broadcastReceiverForPrinter;
    }
```

The problem is here that the changes are tracked for both , if I get disconnected from printer but not from the second device I am still receiving that both of them are disconnected. Whenever one of the actions above(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED,BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED) is triggered for one device , then it gets triggered even for the other device.
The problem I think it has to do with this line

**BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);**

this device the first time points to the mac address of printer on both broadcastreceivers and the second time points to the mac address of second device or is it just random picking one of the devices mac address.
And also I am suspicious that I am using the same UUID for connecting them both to my application and for that reason I am not receiving **device** as unique but a mix of them , but I cannot connect to others UUID except the default SPP one.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering about this problem I found the solution. I created just one broadcast receiver for both of them and this line

**BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);**

is getting me both of the devices so I am just comparing them to the mac address of each of them, below you can find the implementation.

```
 private IntentFilter filterForBoth() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
        return filter;
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver receiveBroadcastForBoth() {
        broadcastReceiverForBoth = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (device.getAddress().equals(PrinterConnectionService.PRINTER_MAC_ADDRESS)) {
                    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "PRINTER CONNECTED: ");                       
 btnConnectToPrinter.setChecked(true);
                    } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "PRINTER DISCONNECTED: "); 
                        btnConnectToPrinter.setChecked(false);
                    }
                    else {
                        btnConnectToPrinter.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }
                else  if (device.getAddress().equals(SecondDevice.Second_MAC_ADDRESS)) {
                    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "CONNECTED: "); 
                        btnSecondDevice.setChecked(true);
                    } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "DISCONNECTED: "); //Device found
                        btnSecondDevice.setChecked(false);
                    } else {
                        btnSecondDevice.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        return broadcastReceiverForBoth;
    }
```